# Servicestack - enabling CORS for error response from Validation plugin?

Tags: cors, servicestack

I'm running into CORS headers not being set properly (all CORS headers are missing) for failed validation (400 returns). I'm using the validation feature plug in but I'm not using the CORS plugin. Instead I'm using the EnableCors attribute on a service by service basis.

A 401 response from my auth end point does have the headers set properly - I *think* I accomplished this by:

```
typeof(Authenticate).AddAttributes(
            new RestrictAttribute(RequestAttributes.HttpPost | RequestAttributes.HttpOptions),
            new EnableCorsAttribute(allowedMethods: "POST", allowedHeaders: "Authorization,Content-Type"));
```

The service missing CORS headers in response when failing validation:

```
[EnableCors(allowedMethods:"POST", allowedHeaders: "Authorization,Content-Type")]
public sealed class MyService : Service
{ 
    ...
    [Authenticate]
    public CustomResponse Post(CustomRequest request)
    {
        //some logic
        return result;
    }
    ...
}
```

Registering routes via attribute on Dto:

```
[Route("/myroute","POST, OPTIONS")]
public class CustomRequest: IReturn<CustomResponse>
{
    ...
}
```

I can provide more details if needed. I know I can add a custom response filter to 'get it done' but I'm wondering if there's a better solution and I have something misconfigured.

Update:

A simple global response filter does not work - Instead - it seems like you need to add the response filter in the plugin's ErrorResponseFilter...

```
 this.Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature()
 {
     ErrorResponseFilter = (validationRes, resp) =>
     {
         if (resp is HttpError)
         {
              var obj = resp as HttpError;
              obj.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          }
          return resp;
      }
  });
```

I specifically need this response header because the response body will be blocked by some browsers if it is not set. Again any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[EnableCors]` is a Request Filter Attribute that's get executed after the Global Filters where as Validation Filters are executed using a Global Request Filter. To have `[EnableCors]` executed before the Validation Filter it needs a Priority `<0`.

Which you can dynamically with something like:

```
typeof(MyService).AddAttributes(
    new EnableCorsAttribute(allowedMethods: "POST", 
        allowedHeaders: "Authorization,Content-Type") { 
            Priority = -1 
        }
);
```

Comment: I'm using 4.5.6 and Priority is read only - is this changing?

Comment: @liz It's already been converted to a [public writable property](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/18e2ff90f135063af9f948712e7e292734b5369e) in v4.5.7 that's [now available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).